# Gridview clean up and neatness asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, web

So my question is this, I have a gridview that filters data from a database when a search keyword is entered. The problem is, that I need it to show some 20 different fields, which is significantly too long for a web page. The gridview goes beyond my asp.net webpage width and off of it. I was wondering if there was any way I could make it neater and easier to read, or fit all the data fields on one page. I'm not too familiar with this, so excuse my lack of know-how in and thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this thread on another site addresses exactly what you're asking:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1277793.aspx/1

Comment: Ahh, this was actually perfect. I didn't know how to make a scroll bar like they suggested. Thank you, and I appreciate everyone else's answers as well!

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions:

1. Show fewer fields.
2. Make your columns really narrow.
3. Make your grid a header row only (contains only minimal info for a record).  Clicking a link in a row will display further details for that item.

Answer (score 2):

Use a DataList, Repeater or ListView so you can layout the row yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/07/31/freeze-asp-net-gridview-headers-by-creating-client-side-extenders.aspx